# How to render PDF documents from .Rmd file using MacOS X Automator?

Tags: r, shell, pandoc, automator, macos-high-sierra

I'm trying to automate the process of generating PDFs from R Markdown files. I am able to run the following command from Terminal and it works:

```
Rscript -e 'library(rmarkdown); rmarkdown::render("/path/to/file.Rmd", "pdf_document")'
```

but using the same command as a shell script in Automator gave me an error that it Rscript was an unknown command. I fixed that by specifying where it should look for Rscript and then another error about requiring pandoc by specifying where pandoc is, but it's giving me an error about requiring xelatex, which I have installed, but I can't figure out how to tell Automator where to find xelatex. Here's the script I'm trying to run:

```
/usr/local/bin/Rscript -e 'library(rmarkdown); 
Sys.setenv(RSTUDIO_PANDOC="/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/pandoc"); 
rmarkdown::render("/path/to/file.Rmd", "pdf_document")'
```

Here's the error message:

```
pandoc: xelatex not found. xelatex is needed for pdf output.
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 41
Execution halted
```

xelatex is located in `/usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-darwin`

I'm running MacOS 10.13.3, R version 3.4.3, and Automator Version 2.8. Any help would be much appreciated!